Why the bleu scores are higher than rouge?
I trained my text retrieval model. When I validated it on bleu score it gave a higher score than rouge.
Let me show my code first if it is code-related problem then it can be identified.
def preprocess_image(image_path):
    # Load the image file
    image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
    # Decode the image
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    # Resize the image to the desired size
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [312, 312])
    # Normalize the image pixels
    image = tf.keras.applications.inception_v3.preprocess_input(image)
    return image


# Define a function to preprocess the test data
def preprocess_test_data(data):
    images = []
    findings = []
    impressions = []
    
    for _, row in data.iterrows():
        image_path = os.path.join(path, row['filename'])
        
        try:
            image = preprocess_image(image_path)
            images.append(image)
        except (tf.errors.NotFoundError, ValueError, TypeError):
            print(f"Warning: Error preprocessing image file: {image_path}. Skipping.")
            continue
        
        finding = str(row["findings"])  # Convert to string
        impression = str(row["impression"])  # Convert to string
        findings.append(finding)
        impressions.append(impression)
    
    if not images:
        print("Warning: No valid image data found.")
    
    return images, findings, impressions

# Preprocess the test data
test_images, test_findings, test_impressions = preprocess_test_data(test_data)

# Convert to tensors
test_images = tf.stack(test_images) if test_images else tf.zeros((0,))

# Preprocess text data using Tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(test_findings + test_impressions)

test_findings_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_findings)
test_impressions_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_impressions)

test_findings = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(test_findings_sequences)
test_impressions = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(test_impressions_sequences)

def decode_text(indices):
    if isinstance(indices, np.ndarray):
        indices = indices.tolist()
    if not indices:
        return ""
    return ' '.join([tokenizer.index_word.get(idx, "") for idx in indices if idx != 0])


def data_generator(images, findings, impressions, batch_size):
    num_samples = len(images)
    num_batches = (num_samples + batch_size - 1) // batch_size

    for batch_idx in range(num_batches):
        start_idx = batch_idx * batch_size
        end_idx = min(start_idx + batch_size, num_samples)

        batch_images = images[start_idx:end_idx]
        batch_findings = findings[start_idx:end_idx]
        batch_impressions = impressions[start_idx:end_idx]

        yield batch_images, batch_findings, batch_impressions


@tf.function
def generate_predictions(model, images, findings, impressions):
    # Reshape the finding tensor to match the expected input shape
    findings = tf.reshape(findings, shape=(-1,))
    # Reshape the impression tensor to match the expected input shape
    impressions = tf.reshape(impressions, shape=(-1,))

    # Get the dynamic shape of the embeddings
    finding_shape = tf.shape(findings)
    impression_shape = tf.shape(impressions)

    # Pad the shorter tensor to match the length of the longer tensor
    if impression_shape[0] < finding_shape[0]:
        padding = [[0, finding_shape[0] - impression_shape[0]]]
        impressions = tf.pad(impressions, padding)
    elif finding_shape[0] < impression_shape[0]:
        padding = [[0, impression_shape[0] - finding_shape[0]]]
        findings = tf.pad(findings, padding)

    # Convert findings and impressions to string sequences
    findings = tf.strings.as_string(findings)
    impressions = tf.strings.as_string(impressions)

    inputs = {
        "image": images,
        "finding": findings,
        "impression": impressions
    }

    text_embeddings, image_embeddings = model(inputs, training=False)
    logits = tf.matmul(text_embeddings, image_embeddings, transpose_b=True) / model.temperature
    predictions = tf.argmax(logits, axis=-1)

    return predictions

references = []
hypotheses = []

batch_size = 8  # Adjust the batch size according to your memory constraints

if tf.size(test_images) > 0:
    for batch_images, batch_findings, batch_impressions in data_generator(test_images, test_findings, test_impressions, batch_size):
        batch_predictions = generate_predictions(clip_model, batch_images, batch_findings, batch_impressions)
        
        batch_hypotheses = [decode_text(pred) for pred in batch_predictions.numpy()]
        batch_references = [[decode_text(finding), decode_text(impression)] for finding, impression in zip(batch_findings, batch_impressions)]

        # Filter out empty or invalid strings
        valid_indices = [i for i, (hyp, ref) in enumerate(zip(batch_hypotheses, batch_references)) if hyp and ref[0] and ref[1]]
        
        hypotheses.extend([batch_hypotheses[i] for i in valid_indices])
        references.extend([batch_references[i] for i in valid_indices])

smoothing_functions = [
    SmoothingFunction().method0,
    SmoothingFunction().method1,
    SmoothingFunction().method2,
    SmoothingFunction().method3,
    SmoothingFunction().method4,
    SmoothingFunction().method5,
    SmoothingFunction().method6,
    SmoothingFunction().method7
]

for i, smoothing_function in enumerate(smoothing_functions):
    sentence_bleu_scores = []

    for hyp, ref in zip(hypotheses, references):
        sentence_bleu_score = sentence_bleu(ref, hyp, weights=(1.0, 0, 0, 0), smoothing_function=smoothing_function)
        sentence_bleu_scores.append(sentence_bleu_score)

    avg_sentence_bleu_score = sum(sentence_bleu_scores) / len(sentence_bleu_scores)
    print(f"Average sentence-level BLEU-1 score with smoothing method {i} on the test dataset: {avg_sentence_bleu_score}")

# Calculate BLEU scores
bleu2_score = corpus_bleu(references, hypotheses, weights=(0.5, 0.5))
bleu3_score = corpus_bleu(references, hypotheses, weights=(0.33, 0.33, 0.33))
bleu4_score = corpus_bleu(references, hypotheses, weights=(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25))
print(f"BLEU-2 score: {bleu2_score}")
print(f"BLEU-3 score: {bleu3_score}")
print(f"BLEU-4 score: {bleu4_score}")

# Calculate ROUGE scores
rouge = Rouge()
rouge_scores = rouge.get_scores(hypotheses, [' '.join(ref) for ref in references], avg=True)
print(f"ROUGE-1 score: {rouge_scores['rouge-1']['f']}")
print(f"ROUGE-2 score: {rouge_scores['rouge-2']['f']}")
print(f"ROUGE-L score: {rouge_scores['rouge-l']['f']}")

The results from the above code are as follows
Average sentence-level BLEU-1 score with smoothing method 0 on the test dataset: 0.523869954459481
Average sentence-level BLEU-1 score with smoothing method 1 on the test dataset: 0.523869954459481
Average sentence-level BLEU-1 score with smoothing method 2 on the test dataset: 0.523869954459481
Average sentence-level BLEU-1 score with smoothing method 3 on the test dataset: 0.523869954459481
Average sentence-level BLEU-1 score with smoothing method 4 on the test dataset: 0.523869954459481
Average sentence-level BLEU-1 score with smoothing method 5 on the test dataset: 0.6718031034767904
Average sentence-level BLEU-1 score with smoothing method 6 on the test dataset: 0.523869954459481
Average sentence-level BLEU-1 score with smoothing method 7 on the test dataset: 0.6718031034767904
BLEU-2 score: 0.32831375074529784
BLEU-3 score: 0.23238644316373192
BLEU-4 score: 0.17094282338431527
ROUGE-1 score: 0.1483522778773942
ROUGE-2 score: 0.006972642323952143
ROUGE-L score: 0.1301592204120029

According to the smoothing functions the highest values for b1 and b2 are 0.67 and 0.52 in that case and according to the previous researches, the Rouge score should be like 0.42 as compared to b1 0.52.
Can I use some smoothing type function with Rouge also??
